# Add a new element with node childs in a XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, label, element

I have a xml that is something like this:

```
<Servers>
  <MyNewServer>
    <Host>10.10.10.2</Host>
    <Port>12</Port>
    <User>MyUser</User>
    <Password>NkbgKnF9g96EYgxG3qRdCNY2KR6Xd5+0uqpY9KOCl4k=</Password>
  </MyNewServer>
</Servers>
```

I'm trying to add a new server below of "NyNewServer" label and add the same child elements in blank (Host, Port, User and Password).

I'm adding now a new element of server but is not with the correct format is displayed horizontal  instead of vertically, and I'm not sure how to add the child elements in blank.

Any idea? I have this:

```
public void XmlNewInterface(string Server)
{
    //Temporal Solution
    xmldoc.Load(XMLInterfacesFile);            
    XmlElement record = xmldoc.CreateElement(Server);
    record.InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    xmldoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(record);

    xmldoc.Save(XMLInterfacesFile);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want similar node like `MyNewServer` with empty host,port tags?

Comment: Yes @HariPrasad but with different server name for example: 
 <Other Server>

Comment: does the solution provided work for you?

Comment: @HariPrasad is Throwing an exeption:
"This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."

Comment: I don't see any issue with the document generated, where exactly it is throwing an exception? while saving the document ?

Comment: @HariPrasad I tried again and it works! may be I did something different!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `Linq` to `Xml`, it simplifies building/constructing Xml. You just need these lines.

```
var doc = XDocument.load(inputfile);

doc.Descendants("Servers").First()
    .Add( new XElement("OneMoreServer",  new [] { 
        new XElement("Host"), 
        new XElement("Port"),
        new XElement("MyUser"),
        new XElement("Password")    
    }));
```

**Output**

```
<Servers>
    <MyNewServer>
        <Host>10.10.10.2</Host>
        <Port>12</Port>
        <User>MyUser</User>
        <Password>NkbgKnF9g96EYgxG3qRdCNY2KR6Xd5+0uqpY9KOCl4k=</Password>
    </MyNewServer>
    <OneMoreServer>
        <Host />
        <Port />
        <MyUser />
        <Password />
    </OneMoreServer>
</Servers>
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uKgbpt)